# Sitecore LinkManager GetItemUrl. Why its so tricky?

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6

I have task to get content's url when smth is changed on website. It like CRUD operation logging (In my case i am logging that urls to other system to further processing). It should work on version 6 and higher.

When i started it seems pretty simple subscribe to event then take item and generate url for it. I subscribed to two events **publish:itemProcessing** (because only here item is not yet removed from web database), **publish:itemProcessed** (for add and update).

This events give me object of time Item, so it seems to get url pretty simple like that

```
var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
options.SiteResolving = true;
var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);
```

And here my problem starts. First i need to have right url and the same way as it is generated on website but here url returns me smth like "http://domain/sitecore/content/Home.aspx".

So I added new methods to find right site from site definitions

```
private List<KeyValuePair<string, SiteContext>> GetSites()
{
            return SiteManager.GetSites()
                .Where(
                    s =>
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Properties["rootPath"]) &&
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s.Properties["startItem"]))
                .Select(
                    d => new KeyValuePair<string, SiteContext>($"{d.Properties["rootPath"]}{d.Properties["startItem"]}",
                        new SiteContext(new SiteInfo(d.Properties))))
                .ToList();
}

public virtual SiteContext GetSiteContext(Item item)
{

            var site = _sites.LastOrDefault(s => item.Paths.FullPath.ToLower().StartsWith(s.Key.ToLower()));
            return site.Value;
}

options.Site = GetSiteContext(Item item);
```

Again issue is not solved because sitecore returns  "**http://127.0.0.1/en.aspx**"

Then i continue reading and understood that site definition should have **targetHostName** (it actually make sense since one site can have multiple domains) but when i add targetHostName now it returns me other link "**://targetHostName/en.aspx**" so http|https is missing. Second problem is that it returns me EN.aspx which means that this page can be accessible throw http://targetHostName/en.aspx and http://targetHostName

Now i have following site definitions

```
 <sites>
      <site name="shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/login" content="master" contentStartItem="/Home" enableWorkflow="true" enableAnalytics="false" analyticsDefinitions="content" xmlControlPage="/sitecore/shell/default.aspx" browserTitle="Sitecore" htmlCacheSize="2MB" registryCacheSize="3MB" viewStateCacheSize="200KB" xslCacheSize="5MB" />
      <site name="login" virtualFolder="/sitecore/login" physicalFolder="/sitecore/login" enableAnalytics="false" database="core" domain="sitecore" disableXmlControls="true" />
      <site name="admin" virtualFolder="/sitecore/admin" physicalFolder="/sitecore/admin" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" domain="sitecore" loginPage="/sitecore/admin/login.aspx" />
      <site name="service" virtualFolder="/sitecore/service" physicalFolder="/sitecore/service" />
      <site name="modules_shell" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/shell" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="core" domain="sitecore" content="master" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
      <site name="modules_website" virtualFolder="/sitecore modules/web" physicalFolder="/sitecore modules/web" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" language="en" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" />
      <site name="website" hostName="sitecore6.target|sitecore6.local" targetHostName="sitecore6.target" schema="http" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
      <site name="scheduler" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
      <site name="system" enableAnalytics="false" domain="sitecore" />
      <site name="publisher" domain="sitecore" enableAnalytics="false" enableWorkflow="true" />
    </sites>
```

And link manager settings

```
 <linkManager defaultProvider="sitecore">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="sitecore" type="Sitecore.Links.LinkProvider, Sitecore.Kernel" addAspxExtension="true" alwaysIncludeServerUrl="false" encodeNames="true" languageEmbedding="asNeeded" languageLocation="filePath" lowercaseUrls="false" shortenUrls="true" useDisplayName="false" />
      </providers>
    </linkManager>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is occurring because of where you are generating the link. When you have the `AlwaysIncludeServerUrl` option set to true, Sitecore will use the current `Sitecore.Context.Site` information to work out the server Url.

To set the http or https section, you need to add an attribute called `scheme` to your site definition - I think you just have a typo as you had one called `schema`:

```
<sites>
    <site name="website" hostName="sitecore6.target|sitecore6.local" targetHostName="sitecore6.target" scheme="http" virtualFolder="/" physicalFolder="/" rootPath="/sitecore/content" startItem="/home" database="web" domain="extranet" allowDebug="true" cacheHtml="true" htmlCacheSize="10MB" registryCacheSize="0" viewStateCacheSize="0" xslCacheSize="5MB" filteredItemsCacheSize="2MB" enablePreview="true" enableWebEdit="true" enableDebugger="true" disableClientData="false" />
</sites>
```

During a publish event, that `Context.Site` will be the `shell` website. So it will not pickup the `targetHostName` for your `website` definition.

To force that, you need to use a `SiteContextSwitcher`

```
var website = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetSite("website");
using (new SiteContextSwitcher(website))
{
    var options = LinkManager.GetDefaultUrlOptions();
    options.AlwaysIncludeServerUrl = true;
    options.SiteResolving = true;
    var url = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(item, options);
}
```

Then the Url will be generated using the website's `targetHostName` and should generate how you are expecting.

Just one last note - best practice would be to patch the new Site definition via an include file rather than edit the main Sitecore config. Check out your include folder, there should be a `SiteDefinition.config.example` file in there. It shows you how to do it.

Comment: I will accept this answer since it is a bit more elegant way to set site. I switched to sitecore 8 and now it work, so probably in version 6 there was bug